# Нахождение дублей фраз в тексте

Tags: python, list

Есть задача проверять текст на дублирующиеся предложения. когда перенесли пару абзацев, а старый кусок не удалили. замысел - побить весь текст на фразы(запись в списке), сделать два списка - брать фразу из одного и сравнивать с другим. фраза из рабочего списка, с которым сравнивается - удаляется, на следующей итерации список опять приводится к эталонному и из него удаляется следующая фраза. эталонный - lst, рабочий - loop.
по неясной мне причине эталонный список тоже уменьшается, хотя в коде я этого не вижу.

```py
text= 'Атас. Бинго. Атас. Кошерно'
text=text.replace('\n', '')
lst= text.split('.')
ll=len(lst)
print ('первый список', lst)
for l in range (ll):
    loop = lst
    print ('sravni',l, lst[l],loop[l])
    del loop [l]
    print ('лист', lst)
    #print ('sravni222',lst[l],loop[l])
    if lst[l] in loop:
        print ('loop', l, lst[l])
    else:
        pass
print (ll)
print ( lst)
```

много принтов - искал причину.

Answer (score 2):

Списки является ссылочным типа, а это значит, что строка `loop = lst` не копирует список `lst` в переменную `loop`, а лишь объявляет `loop` синонимом переменной `lst`.
Т.е. все изменения в переменной `loop` отразятся и на списке `lst` и наоборот.
Это должно помочь:

```
loop = lst[:]
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, полетело.